# Python: Beautifulsoup - Parse a table

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to loop through a table row by row and print certain td's. I can print each individually, but I am unsure how I can print both td's that are on the same row at the same time. What I want to know is where do I place the for loops and the print tag to get this to work.

```
<div id="main">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><span class="bold">answer</span> </td>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <option value="1|0|%" selected="selected">%</option>
                    <option value="100|0|fraction">fraction</option>
                    <option value="100|0|ratio">ratio</option>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

and my attempt to achieve this is

```
def summary(url, i):
html = wget(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    for row in soup.findAll('div', {'id': 'main'}):
        for ops in row.findAll('tr'):
            for tds1 in ops.findAll('td'):
                for opt in tds1.findAll('option', {'selected': 'selected'}):
                    return opt
        for ops in row.findAll('tr'):
            for tds1 in ops.findAll('td'):
                for spans in tds1.findAll('span', {'class': 'bold'}):
                    return spans
            print (i, opt, spans)
```

Comment: The HTML that you are parsing and expected output would help correct the code

Comment: Are you sure you have `return opt` in your code? That would mean that this code never prints anything. It also looks like there's an issue with indentation: are you sure the lines starting with `soup` are indented?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "print both on the same row at the same time"?

Comment: Soup is not indented.

Comment: Patrick, I want to print the rows as such                       [1,td1, td2]                                                     [2,td1, td2]                                                               and so on

Comment: Either provide a url, or the relevant HTML part. Also, provide the desired output. Otherwise it is difficult to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Think about what you want to do in English, then work out how to translate it to Python.

You want to go row by row, then print both columns that are in the row on the same line. You've already got most of the code that does this:

```
# Go row by row
for ops in row.findAll('tr'):
    # Go column by column
    for tds1 in ops.findAll('td'):
        # Print columns on the same line
        print(tds1, end=' ')
    # Make sure to end each line after the last column
    print()
```

I don't know what all that other code of yours is for—why you're doing the outer loop twice, why you're searching for other things within the column, why you're returning as soon as you find the first value, etc.—but the `print` with `end = ' '` is the part you're missing: that's the way you print multiple things on the same line.

Comment: I don't want to print all the td tags or all of the data in the td tags, just the first td and the option select in another td tag. I added the html format I am trying to parse

Comment: I am not sure how to structure what I am trying to do. I am getting an error when I run the code. `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python /Users/mike/PycharmProjects/convertHtml/tables_parse.py
  File "/Users/mike/PycharmProjects/convertHtml/tables_parse.py", line 42
    print(tds1, end=' ')
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Process finished with exit code 1`

Comment: @Marqui678: OK, so you're using Python 2.7, but trying to use Python 3-style `print`-as-a-function calls. Your original code gets away with this, although it does add extra parentheses and `repr` each element instead of `str`ing it, because it doesn't use any keyword arguments; I've added `end=' '`, which makes it break. If you want to do 3.x-style `print` in 2.7, you need to `from __future__ import print_function` at the top of your file. If you want to do 2.x-style `print` statements, get rid of those parentheses in your `print` statements, and change the `end=' '` to just a trailing `,`.